# JQuery Data table + table state is not preserved

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm working with JQuery data tables and my table is paginated. With each row I have an associated checkbox. Say I have checked two of those checkbox in the first page, then I go to the second page and come back to the first, I find that the state of the first page is lost. Is there any attribute in data-table which will help me save the state of the table.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using ajax data or a static table?

Answer (score 0):

javascript has no state between separate pages - you'll need to implement a server-side solution to store state

Comment: Could also be a client side solution. Local Storage etc ... But I think you got the question wrong. The OP asked for jquery dataTables which is plugin to display paginated tables. It does not need any page reloads. https://datatables.net/

Comment: OP says he changes page - I misunderstood his context of 'page'